# How to simplify $\iint \delta \left( t-\frac1c\left(\sqrt{(x_1-z_1)^2+z_2^2}-\sqrt{z_1^2+z_2^2}\right) \right)dz_1dz_2$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, distribution-theory

I've been doing some mathematical modelling in geophysics and the following integration came up. Are there any identities for the Dirac Delta that can be used to simplify this expression:

$$\iint \delta \left( t-\frac1c\left(\sqrt{(x_1-z_1)^2+z_2^2}-\sqrt{z_1^2+z_2^2}\right) \right)dz_1dz_2$$

**Edit**: To make matters more interesting/challenging (or worse) there are other factors in the integrend, i.e., the full expression is:

$$\iint \frac{\rho(z_1)}{\sqrt{(x_1-z_1)^2+z_2^2}\sqrt{z_1^2+z_2^2}}\delta \left( t-\frac1c\left(\sqrt{(x_1-z_1)^2+z_2^2}-\sqrt{z_1^2+z_2^2}\right) \right)dz_1dz_2$$

where $\rho$ is a some random function. So the question now boils down to: Will Fubini together with

$$\delta(f(x)) = \sum_{i}\frac{\delta(x - x_i)}{|f'(x_i)|}$$

(as pointed out in the answers below) suffice for a simplification still?

Comment: the range of integration for $z_1$ is $(0, \infty)$ while for $z_2$ it is the entire real line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging from the setup of the problem, I'll assume $x_1, t > 0$ and only study that case.
Let $\lambda = \frac12x_1$ and $\mu = \frac12 ct$. Introduce a bunch of variables:

$$
\begin{cases}
(x,y) = (z_1 - \lambda, z_2)\\
r_1 = \sqrt{(x+\lambda)^2 + y^2} = \sqrt{z_1^2+z_2^2}\\
r_2 = \sqrt{(x-\lambda)^2 + y^2} = \sqrt{(z_1-x_1)^2 + z_2^2}\\
(u,v) = \left(\frac{r_1 - r_2}{2},\frac{r_1 + r_2}{2}\right)
\end{cases}$$
The actual integral you want to integral can be rewritten as

$$\mathcal{I} = \int_{[-\lambda,\infty)\times(-\infty,\infty)}\rho(x+\lambda)\delta\left(\frac2c(u+\mu)\right)\frac{dxdy}{r_1r_2}$$

Since the integrand is symmetric with respect to the $y$-axis, we can replace
the integral by one over the upper $(x,y)$ plane:
$$\int_{[-\lambda,\infty)\times(-\infty,\infty)}\cdots\quad\leftrightarrow\quad 2\int_{[-\lambda,\infty)\times [0,\infty)}\cdots$$
Change variables to $(u,v)$, the upper $(x,y)$ plane corresponds to the
strip $[-\lambda,\lambda] \times [\lambda,\infty)$ in the $(u,v)$ plane.
Notice
$$\begin{align}
4uv &= (r_1-r_2)(r_1+r_2) = r_1^2 - r_2^2 =  4\lambda x\\
u^2 + v^2 &= \frac14\left((r_1-r_2)^2+(r_1+r_2)^2\right)
= \frac12\left(r_1^2+r_2^2\right) 
= x^2+y^2+\lambda^2
\end{align}
$$
A point $(x,y) \in [-\lambda,\infty) \times [0,\infty)$ is equivalent to corresponding $(u,v)$ belongs to following region:
$$\Omega \stackrel{def}{=} \{ (u,v) \in [ -\lambda,\lambda ] \times [ \lambda, \infty ) : uv \ge -\lambda^2 \}$$

In terms of $(u,v)$, the area element has the form
$$dx \wedge dy = dx \wedge \frac{dy^2}{2y} = 
\frac{1}{2\lambda y} d(\lambda x)\wedge d(x^2+y^2+\lambda^2)
= \frac{1}{2\lambda y} d(uv)\wedge d(u^2+v^2)\\
= \frac{1}{\lambda y} (udv + vdu)\wedge(udu + vdv)
= \frac{v^2-u^2}{\lambda y} du\wedge dv
= \frac{r_1r_2}{\lambda y} du\wedge dv
$$
Since
$$y^2 = u^2 + v^2 - x^2 - \lambda^2 = u^2 + v^2 - \frac{u^2v^2}{\lambda^2} - \lambda^2
= \frac{1}{\lambda^2}(v^2 - \lambda^2)(\lambda^2-u^2)$$
We find
$$\frac{dxdy}{r_1r_2} = \frac{dudv}{\lambda y} = 
\frac{dudv}{\sqrt{(v^2-\lambda^2)(\lambda^2-u^2)}}
$$
and hence
$$\mathcal{I} = 2\int_\Omega \rho(x+\lambda)\frac{\delta(\frac{2}{c}(u+\mu))dudv}{\sqrt{(v^2-\lambda)^2(\lambda^2-u^2)}}$$

Apply the formula mentioned in other answers, we have
$$\delta\left(\frac2c(u+\mu)\right) = \frac{c}{2}\delta(u + \mu)$$

Integrate the delta function over $u$, the $u$ get fixed to $-\mu$.

When $\mu > \lambda$, the line $u = -\mu$ lies outside the strip 
$[-\lambda,\lambda] \times [\lambda,\infty)$ and $\mathcal{I}$ vanishes.

For $0 < \mu < \lambda$, the integral reduces to

$$\mathcal{I} = \frac{c}{\sqrt{\lambda^2-\mu^2}} \int_\lambda^{\lambda^2/\mu}\frac{\rho\left(\lambda  - \frac{\mu v}{\lambda}\right) d v}{\sqrt{v^2-\lambda^2}}
= \frac{c}{\sqrt{\lambda^2-\mu^2}}\int_0^{\lambda-\mu} \frac{\rho(z_1)dz_1}{\sqrt{(\lambda-z_1)^2-\mu^2}}
$$
The rest of the integral depends on the actual form of $\rho(\cdot)$ and I'll leave that for you.

Comment: Thank you. I'd like to ask: how can I modify the answer if the original integral looks like this $$\iiint \frac{\rho(z_1)}{\sqrt{(x_1-z_1)^2+z_2^2 +z_3^2}\sqrt{z_1^2+z_2^2+z_3^2}}\delta \left( t-\frac1c\left(\sqrt{(x_1-z_1)^2+z_2^2+z_3^2}-\sqrt{z_1^2+z_2^2+z_3^2}\right) \right)dz_1dz_2dz_3$$

Comment: @Iconoclast That case will be even simpler. If one parametrize $(z_1,z_2,z_3)$ as $(x+\lambda,y\cos\theta,y\sin\theta)$, then
$$\frac{dz_1 dz_2 dz_3}{r_1r_2}  = \frac{dx dy}{r_1 r_2}yd\theta = \frac{du dv}{\lambda y}yd\theta = \frac{1}{\lambda}du dv d\theta$$
Integrate over $\theta$ and then over $u$, you will get back essentially the same integral with the ugly square root at the denominator replaced by some constant.

Comment: One last question, you are assuming that $z_1>0$ right? What happens if that assumption is invalid, i.e., $z_1 \in (-\infty, \infty)$?

Comment: @Iconoclast If $z_1$ can be any value, the integral of delta function will be over the whole strip $[-\lambda,\lambda]\times[\lambda,\infty)$ in $uv$-plane and the final integral over $z_1$ will be over $(-\infty,\lambda - \mu)$ when $\mu < \lambda$ and identically zero when $\mu > \lambda$.

Comment: how do you determine that the region $[-\lambda, \infty) \times (-\infty, \infty)$ in the $xy$-plane corresponds to the region $[-\lambda, \lambda] \times [\lambda, \infty)$ in the $uv$-plane? By plotting?

Comment: @Iconoclast the locus for fixed $u$ and $v$ are hyperbolas and ellipses with foci at $(\pm \lambda, 0)$. One just need to figure out what the $(u,v)$ are on the boundary (in this case the real axis).

Comment: From what i can tell if you fix $u$ and $v$ in the equation that relates $u$ and $v$ to $x$ and $y$ then the locus of points obtaining by fixing $u$ and $v$ are two circles with centers at $(\pm \lambda,0)$ and radius $|u \pm v|$.

Comment: @Iconoclast If you fix both $u$ and $v$, then it will be two points (which are intersection of two circles, one with radius $u+v$, the other with $v-u$). If you fix only $u$, then the locus are points whose distance to $(-\lambda,0)$ is greater than that to $(\lambda,0)$ by $2u$ which is a branch of a hyperbola. If you only fix $v$, then the locus are points whose sum of distance to the two points are $2v$ which is an ellipse.

Comment: achillehui, Hello again. It seems that I mistake in my original post, the exact expression is $$\iiint \frac{\rho(z_3)}{\sqrt{(x_1-z_1)^2+z_2^2+z_3^2}\sqrt{z_1^2+z_2^2+z_3^2}}\delta \left( t-\frac1c\left(\sqrt{(x_1-z_1)^2+z_2^2+z_3^2}+\sqrt{z_1^2+z_2^2+z_3^2}\right) \right)dz_1dz_2dz_3$$ where the function $\rho$ depends on the thrid coordinate $z_3$ and not $z_1$. I cant seem to figure out an appropriate change of variables for this situation, can you kindly help please?

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$$ \delta \left [g(x) \right ] = \sum_{k=1}^N \frac{\delta(x-x_k)}{|g'(x_k)|}$$

where $g(x_k)=0$ for $k=1,2,\ldots,N$.

Comment: I guess what i have is $\delta[g(x_1, x_2)]$. How would the above expression change in case of two variables.

Comment: Well, you are still integrating over one of the variables first.  Let that variable be $x$ in my notation.

Comment: Just a question: Shouldn't it be $|g'(x_k)|$?

Comment: @FourierTransform: yes, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

First of all use Fubinit's theorem to "change" the integration:

$$\int \text{d}z_1 \int \delta \left( t-\frac{\sqrt{(x_1-z_1)^2+z_2^2}-\sqrt{(z_1^2+z_2^2)}}{c} \right)\text{d}z_2$$

Now the integration of a Delta "function" of the type

$$\delta(f(x))$$

can be done via the definition of the delta "function" of a function:

$$\delta(f(x)) = \sum_{i}\frac{\delta(x - x_i)}{|f'(x_i)|}$$

Where $i$ runs over all the possible number of roots of the equation

$$f(x_i) = 0$$

Can you proceed?

**Hint**

Despite you have two variables of integration, thanks to Fubini you can first integrate in $z_2$ (or $z_1$) and then in the other one, so first of all, treat one of the two as a constant and find the roots in terms of $z_2$.